# BouncyCastleProvider class not found in Grails 2.5.0

Tags: grails, classloader, bouncycastle

I have a Grails project in which I want to use Bouncycastle to calculate a Sha512 hash of a string.

When I call `Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider())` I get the following error message:

```
| Error 2015-06-21 15:34:53,242 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/BouncyCastleProvider
Message: org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/BouncyCastleProvider
Line | Method
->>   49 | doCall                           in BootStrap$_closure1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    327 | evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock in grails.util.Environment
|    320 | executeForEnvironment . . . . .  in     ''
|    296 | executeForCurrentEnvironment     in     ''
|    262 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker                        in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run                              in java.lang.Thread
Caused by ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
->>  366 | run                              in java.net.URLClassLoader$1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    355 | run                              in     ''
|    354 | findClass . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.net.URLClassLoader
|    425 | loadClass                        in java.lang.ClassLoader
|     49 | doCall . . . . . . . . . . . . . in BootStrap$_closure1
|    327 | evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock in grails.util.Environment
|    320 | executeForEnvironment . . . . .  in     ''
|    296 | executeForCurrentEnvironment     in     ''
|    262 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker                        in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run                              in java.lang.Thread
```

In my IDE (IntelliJ) the import `import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider` appears to be resolved  and I can navigate to the location of the class.

Why is the `BouncyCastle` class not found when I execute the application?

Comment: OK, I just realized I can calculate the hash without adding BouncyCastle as SecurityProvider....but nevertheless, I still don't understand, why I can't load a class which is included in the Grails distribution...

Answer (score 0):

Have you added an entry for the provider in the JCE Security Policy file of the JRE you are using?

```
JAVA_HOME\jre\lib\security\java.security
```

*n is one more than the last entry already present*

```
security.provider.n=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
```

http://bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Provider+Installation